# Scale in plot graph from RStudio only shows labels inbetween on y axis and leaves out the ends 5, and -25

Tags: r, plot

[image: plot graph]

```
y = c(2.9, 3.1, −1.2, −1.1, −3.3 ,3.7 ,1.9 ,−0.3, −5.9, −7.9,
      −5.5, −7.2, −4.1 ,−8.6, −5.5, −0.7, −5.1, −7.1, −4.2,
      0.9, −6.1, −4.1, −4.8, −11.3 −9.3, −10.7, −1.8, −7.4, −22.9)
x = c(1971:1999)

plot(x, y)
```

I'm new to R and can't seem to figure out how to make the labels inclusive for the whole y range. The first and last numbers appear to be excluded by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `ylim = c(-25, 5)` to the `plot` call:

```r
y = c(2.9, 3.1, −1.2, −1.1, −3.3 ,3.7 ,1.9 ,−0.3, −5.9, −7.9,
      −5.5, −7.2, −4.1 ,−8.6, −5.5, −0.7, −5.1, −7.1, −4.2,
      0.9, −6.1, −4.1, −4.8, −11.3 −9.3, −10.7, −1.8, −7.4, −22.9)
x = c(1972:1999)

plot(x, y, ylim = c(-25, 5))
```

[image]